# Чтение из файла string с пробелом

Tags: c++, строки, fstream

Как считать string с пробелом из файла?

Пример: 436   Steve   CD 5678-4   Opel (класс Car)
В классе Car перегрузил >>

Comment: не хочется соединять две стринги. Может есть какой-нибудь вариант работы не через пробелы, а через табы?

Comment: Так, судя по тому, что ответ не нравится... Что именно вам нужно? Поясните понятнее, чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Значит считываю с файла пример, это все поля класса Car, когда оно считывает CD 5678-4 (номер машины) бьет на две строки. Вопрос в том можно ли без склеивания двух строк CD и 5678-4 обойтись

Comment: А если там будет три слова? :) Разделяйте поля чем-то при вводе - чем угодно - и используйте `getline` с разделителем (см. ответ). См. также https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV

Comment: так именно поэтому перегружены >> чтобы сразу инициализировать поля

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char buf[SIZE];
stream.getline(buf,SIZE);
```

или

```
string s;
getline(stream,s);
```

Можно с нестандартным разделителем -

```
getline(stream,s,'\t');
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это искал